# Mystery errors on the VL813 USB Hub on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb, usb-device

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with a 7 port external USB hub. This box is implemented as two 4 port Via VL813 hubs.

On the Linux side from lsusb this looks like

```
Bus 004 Device 009: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 003 Device 060: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 003 Device 026: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
```

There are really two chips in each VL813 0813 on Bus 004 handles USB 3 and 2813 on Bus 003 handles USB 2.

For Bus 4 lsusb -t shows

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
```

showing the nesting of the two 4 port chips to implement the 7 port external box.

OK, here finally is the mystery, syslog shows continual messages

```
Mar  5 12:01:52 orac kernel: [2068420.628891] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  5 12:01:52 orac kernel: [2068420.633615] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  5 12:01:52 orac kernel: [2068420.875834] usb 4-6.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar  5 12:02:38 orac kernel: [2068466.757899] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  5 12:02:38 orac kernel: [2068466.762412] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  5 12:02:39 orac kernel: [2068467.004831] usb 4-6.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

This is with nothing connected to the ports on the external box.

Besides all the messages in syslog every few day all USB devices hang, even those not related to the external box. You can see this on the last hang where the xhci_hcd driver shuts down just 6 seconds after the usb 4-6.1 message with nothing intervening.

```
Mar  4 21:55:34 orac kernel: [2017642.022271] usb 4-6: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  4 21:55:34 orac kernel: [2017642.025784] usb 4-6: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.323348] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.323358] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.579344] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.579350] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USBSTS: 0x00000000
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.579354] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.579375] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for stop endpoint command
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.579399] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Mar  4 21:55:40 orac kernel: [2017647.579409] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
```

Since the keyboard (which is not even on the box) is dead I have to login over the network and unbind and rebind the xhci_hcd driver to recover USB. So I'm suspicious that its related to the constant Bus 4 complaints.

I'm not sure if its the USB Hub box, or something in Linux thats the problem.

Ideas?